# Need help in capturing HTTP Request sent from View results tree sampler in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have an XML request with me, which needs to be sent over an IBM MQ channel. The client has not provided us the MQ connection details and has asked us to provide parametrised XML which they will manually copy and post it to MQ till the time they don't get the connection details

The issue is the XML's are big and they have to manually change each attribute and then Post it to MQ and thus they are asking for this process to be automated.

The idea is they will provide the data sheet and I would parameterize the xml, which I have already done.

I am also getting the different XML's with different data set in the HTTP request under View results tree.

The thing is I dont want to manually copy those request XML's and save it to notepad.

Is there a way using which I can directly save those Request XML's to a file?

Capturing Response is easy but how to capture the request itself!! Wejust need to capture the request!

PS: I have tried multiple option right from Bean shell to some Plugins as well as making changes to the User properties file of Jmeter but nothing worked.

```
It dosent matter if the requests are failing I just need to capture that request and save each of them seperately for multiple threads.

I have just executed 1 thread in the sample picture attached.Thanks for help in advance.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest is going for the [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin/), the relevant configuration would be:

[image]

```
---------REQUEST----------------------\r\n|requestData|\r\n
```

As the result you will get the file which looks like:

```
---------REQUEST----------------------
POST http://example.com/

POST data:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <note>
        <to>jane</to>
  <from>john</from>
        <heading>hi</heading>
  <body>how are you</body>
</note>

[no cookies]

---------REQUEST----------------------
POST http://example.com/

POST data:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <note>
        <to>john</to>
  <from>jane</from>
        <heading>Re:hi</heading>
  <body> I'm perfect!</body>
</note>

[no cookies]
```

You can install Flexible File Writer using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, 

I did used the flexible file writer but I was unaware of the Setting:- 
Record each sample as:- ---------REQUEST----------------------\r\n|requestData|\r\n>

I used this and it worked. Thanks for the solution.

Is this setting documented somewhere? like a standard documentation. It would be helpful for others as well if they need some more help.

Thanks Again! I will mark the solution as working

Comment: I believe I provided a [link to the reference guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin/), there is also [official documentation](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/) on the Flexible File Writer (not too verbose though)

Comment: ohh! Yes you did provide the link. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably missing configuration, Either in Test Plan level, check the Functional checkbox

[image]

Or Configure button in Listener and check relevant Request checkboxes

[image]